# Using Gaze-based pointer with 3D objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

I recently downloaded **Unity 5.6.0f3** and imported Google VR SDK **1.4.0** to be used in my project. I attached the *GvrPointerInputModule* to my *EventSystem*, placed *GvrViewerMain / GvrReticlePointer* as children of my *MainCamera*, placed the *GvrPointerPhysicsRaycaster* script as a component of my *MainCamera*, and my 3D objects all have colliders. Is there anything I am missing from this equation to get gaze-based interaction working with my Event Triggers?

Comment: Could you please share with us a scenario that you tried and didn't work as you expected?

Comment: You could also try the example scenes provided by Google, I'm positive one of them had gaze interaction.